# How can I delete all of the points from a highcharts series

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

Using HighCharts I want to delete all of the points from a series, so that I can add a new dataset. Is there a better approach than looping through all of the points, and removing them one by one like this?:

```
for(var i=0; i < chart.series[0].points.length; i++){
    chart.series[0].points[i].remove()
}
```

I have also seen references to ways of removing the entire series `chart.series[0].remove();`
This seems quicker to remove the points, but I don't understand how to create an empty series with the same properties and name that points can be added to, which is why I chose to delete the points.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to delete some points from your serie I sugest you to store your serie points, remove the points you want and then use `setData` to set your serie data again.

If you want to **remove all points without remove the serie** you can use `chart.series[0].setData([]);`.

You can use `addPoint` to add points one by one or `setData` for more than one.
There're some examples which shows how to do it.
[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TjTn7/)
[**reference**](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#object-Series)

Comment: `chart.series[0].setData([]);` worked - I did not realize an empty array could be passed in.