# How do I get rid of a subset of series points off of highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a highchart that generates data like so:

[image]

What I want to do is when I click the Major Versions drop down button and select a version, the version is displayed and the rest of the series points are removed like so:

[image]

As reference, I've used this stackoverflow question as a guide [removing datapoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364549/how-can-i-delete-all-of-the-points-from-a-highcharts-series). However when I try to implement this in coffeescript like so:

```
chart = $('#vulnerability_version_chart').highcharts()
chart.series[0].setData([])
chart.series[1].setData([])
chart.series[2].setData([])
chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(calculateCategory(releases))
chart.series[0].setData(calculateY(releases), calculateHighVulns(releases))
chart.series[1].setData(calculateY(releases), calculateMediumVulns(releases))
chart.series[2].setData(calculateY(releases), calculateLowVulns(releases))
```

All that this code does is remove all the data points and it doesn't rerender with the new points. I've looked into `update()`, `redraw`, `reflow` and I am still unable to get it to render. What am I missing here?
HOw can I remove the points after 1.4.4? I've tried `setData and for loops. This doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Do you have live example of your chart? Do you have any errors in your console? how chart.series[0].setData(calculateY(releases), calculateHighVulns(releases)) works?

Comment: What is `calculateHighVulns(releases)`? The second argument for the `setData()` function is a `boolean` value that specifies whether or not to redraw the chart, but you seem to be passing it something else, which is probably evaluating to `false`, and therefore not redrawing the chart.